# Converter Varchar para Time em SQL com dados com mais de 24 horas

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou desenvolvendoo uma query em SQL e no caso preciso converter um campo de horas que está em varchar para time para depois efetuar uma media deste campo(vou usar o Datediff junto). O problema, é que o CONVERT só faz a conversão para dados até 23:59:59, se for acima disso ele não consegue converter.

O que poderia fazer neste caso? No caso a Query que estou usando é a seguinte

```
SELECT CONVERT(time,[TEMPO INDISPONÍVEL], 114) as tempo_indisponivel 
FROM [Ocorrencias].[dbo].[ind_operadora]
```

Lembrando que o campo [TEMPO INDISPONÍVEL] é Varchar.

Comment: Creio que você esteja misturando conceitos. `time` no SQL Server se refere a um ponto específico de data e hora, não se refere a intervalo de tempo decorrido. Eu creio que seja possível somar um `time` a um numérico, onde o numérico serviria como a quantidade de horas em um intervalo e a soma é interpretado como "qual será o horário depois de decorrer um intervalo de tempo a partir da minha hora base"

Answer (score 1):

Como o seu campo `tempo_indisponivel` refere-se a [durações de tempo](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/working-with-time-spans-and-durations-in-sql-server) que podem conter valores maiores que 24h, não é possível convertê-lo para o tipo `Time`.

O campo do tipo [Time](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/data-types/time-transact-sql) no SqlServer refere-se à hora de um dia baseada em um relógio de 24h. Os valores permitidos devem estar no intervalo entre `00:00:00.0000000` e `23:59:59.9999999`.

Minha sugestão seria trabalhar com a unidade de tempo em segundos (usando `int`). Para converter para segundos, considerando que o campo `varchar` armazene o tempo no formato `horas:minutos:segundos`, basta fazer:

```
declare @tempo varchar(9) = '72:05:38'

select cast( left( @tempo,charindex(':', @tempo) - 1) as int) * 3600
       +cast( substring( @tempo,charindex(':', @tempo) + 1 ,2) as int) * 60
       +cast( right( @tempo,2) as int) as tempo_em_segundos

--Resultado: 259538
```

Para converter de volta o tempo de duração em segundos para o tipo `varchar`, basta fazer:

```
declare @tempo_em_segundos int = 259538

select cast(@tempo_em_segundos/3600 as varchar(3))
      +':'+right('0'+cast(@tempo_em_segundos%3600/60 as varchar(2)) ,2)
      +':'+right('0'+cast(@tempo_em_segundos%60 as varchar(2)) ,2)

--Resultado: '72:05:38'
```

**Outra solução**

Outra forma de trabalhar com "durações de tempo" no SqlServer seria usar o tipo [DateTime](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/sql/t-sql/data-types/datetime-transact-sql) tendo o valor padrão `01/01/1900 00:00:00` como a data inicial (D0).

As durações seriam representadas como um deslocamento a partir de D0. Por exemplo:

```
Duração     Representação em DateTime     Significado
12:30:01    01/01/1900 12:30:01           0 Dia 12h 30min 01seg
25:15:30    02/01/1900 01:15:30           1 Dia 01h 15min 30seg
```

Para converter uma duração de tempo `varchar` para `DateTime`, poderia ser usada a seguinte query:

```
declare @tempo varchar(9) = '72:05:38'

select dateadd
       (day
        ,cast( left( @tempo,charindex(':', @tempo) - 1) as int) / 24
        ,cast( cast( cast( left( @tempo,charindex(':', @tempo) - 1 ) 
                           as int) % 24 
                     as varchar(3)) + substring( @tempo,charindex(':', @tempo) ,6) 
               as datetime) )

--Resultado: 04/01/1900 00:05:38
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá,

Segue um exemplo que utilizo aqui na empresa e que encontrei em algum forum na net, porém se precisar utilizar segundos você terá que fazer uma pequena modificação.

```
declare @tempo table (hora varchar(9))

insert into @tempo values ('23:59')
insert into @tempo values ('03:31')


select minutos_total / 60 as horas, minutos_total % 60 as minutos
from (
select sum(
 cast(left(hora,charindex(':',hora) - 1) as int) * 60 +
 cast(right(hora,len(hora)-charindex(':',hora)) as int)) as minutos_total
from @tempo) as resultado
```

Resultado

```
|horas | minutos|
| 27   |   30   |
```

Espero ter ajudado